# img tag inside anchor tag... read on

Tags: image

So I have add to cart button, which is comprised of an anchor tag that has an image tag inside it. The anchor tag is using a bunch of javascript effects for mouseover etc that does image swap of this image in question etc.

Now, I have a function "AddCartButton" in my codebehind class that handles click event of this anchor tag. This obviously does not work when javascript is disabled. So I replaced the img tag inside the anchor tag with control, but Those swappings are not working for my though.

What are my options? I want the click to be handled by my C# function irrespective of whether javascript is enabled, and I want the mouseover effect when javascript is enabled.

P.S. It is a repost, but there was only 1 view or something for last post, so I changed the title a lil bit.

Comment: post the actual code you're working on

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<a id = "addcartButton" href = "#" runat = "server"  onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onserverclick = "AddCartButton" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1111111111','','../_images/b_addCart_f2.gif',1)">
<img runat = "server" src='../_images/b_addCart.gif' AlternateText="Add to Cart"  name="Image1111111111" width="106" height="29" border="0" />
</a>
</div>
```

So basically I want something that is working even when javascript is disabled. I still want all those mouseover effects etc when javascript is availabel though.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at ImageButton class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx